# sending a gridview in email

Tags: vb.net, email, gridview

I am trying to send selected rows and columns of a grdiview in email and for this i am using this function to do so

```
Public Function gridhtm(ByVal gv As GridView) As String
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        Dim sw As StringWriter = New StringWriter(sb)
        Dim hw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        gv.RenderControl(hw)
        Return sb.ToString
    End Function
```

and for sending email i am sending email like this

```
 email("malik.adeel@shakarganj.com.pk", "[Cheque Approval] GM Finance Reviewed (" & TreeView2.SelectedValue & ")", "<b>Please find below the details of cheques prepared in favour of different parties.</b><br>" & _
                     gridhtm(GridView5))
```

Problem is that when email set it sends the overall gridview to email like this image

[image]

In this there are two rows selected with check box and also i want to skip some columns like `category` `nature` mean i want to send only selected columns in email.But i dnt have any idea to manage this so please give any idea to accomplish this.

Comment: Anyone Please answer to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For printing purposes, remove what you don't want. You can redirect to a "print view page" and print from there. Also, depending on RenderControl(), you may be able to hide those items with CSS before you print.